# apt upgrade results in: ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon; /run/zsysd.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: apt, zfs

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and every time I run an apt upgrade, I get the following error:

```
ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: no such file or directory" 
Setting up zsys (0.4.6) ...
dpkg: error processing package zsys (--configure):
 installed zsys package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zsys
ERROR couldn't connect to zsys daemon: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/zsysd.sock: connect: no such file or directory" 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I know this is related to the experimental zfs, as I noticed it longer takes snapshots.  I have searched around, but cant find anything relevant.

Comment: Also posted at https://askubuntu.com/q/1259745/43344 .